# Error 1064, with csv, sql and php

Tags: php, sql, file, codeigniter, csv

Can somebody help me.
This is the code:

```
public function csv_file()
{

    $file = $_FILES['importeren']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");   
    $filecsv = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ";"); 

    foreach($filecsv as $csv)
    {


        $password = rand(100000,999999);
        //echo $password . '</br>' ;

        $username = $csv;
        $studentnummer = $csv;
        $klas = $csv;
      /*  $voornaam = $csv[3];
        $tv = $csv[4];
        $achternaam = $csv[5];*/

   $query = "INSERT INTO user (fk_klas_ID,admin_ID,username,password,studentnummer) "
                            . "VALUES ('$klas','0','$username', sha1('$password'),$studentnummer');"; 
   $result = $this->db->query($query);
   return $filecsv;
}
}
```

I got this error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL        
server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

INSERT INTO user (fk_klas_ID,admin_ID,username,password,studentnummer) 
VALUES ('Richard','0','Richard', sha1('710565'),Richard');

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I want that you can give a csv file, so that the content comes into the db.
I am using codeigniter

Sorr for my bad english

Comment: The syntax highlighting here shows exactly what your problem is: quotes around the second ($studentnummer) `Richard`

Comment: but that is just a name in the csv file

Comment: Other issues: you're not escaping any of the string values you read from the CSV, or using prepared statements, so a quote character in any of those string values will cause you problems

Comment: Other issues: you're using sha1 for password hashing?!?

Comment: @MarkBaker, `sha1` isn't secure either ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran No, use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password) like Blowfish.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, Are there any test cases to prove `sha1` is insecure ? It will be better if you provide some references. Thanks.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I don't have references for you, but only hashing a password with SHA1 is not enough: it is too fast. With a fast computer (e.g., with fast GPU), you can crack a SHA1 hashed password very fast (within hours, I did it myself a few months ago). You need a strong hashing algorithm with a rather high cost (**and salt**) to be secure enough. The linked functions take care of this all.

Comment: @user2870245 - I've rolled this back to the original version; now the comments and the answer make sense. When you edit a question with answers, please don't replace the existing question with a new one - the answers become meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a quotes in `$studentnummer`.So change the query like this

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO user (fk_klas_ID,admin_ID,username,password,studentnummer) "
                            . "VALUES ('$klas','0','$username', sha1('$password'),'$studentnummer');";
```